# Adding default role on registration with Entrust and Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to learn Laravel and I'm checking some ACL's along the way. Currently I'm testing Entrust/Zizaco and I'm trying to add default role when user is registered.

I've added this to the create function in `RegisterController.php`

```
$user = User::find($create->id);
$role = Role::where('name', '=', 'customers')->firstOrFail();
$user->roles()->attachRole($role->id);
```

This is full function

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user = User::find($create->id);
    $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'customers')->firstOrFail();
    $user->roles()->attachRole($role->id);
    return $user;
}
```

The problem is that the user is created but the role isn't assigned. No errors also. Can anyone help me a bit here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach the roles directly to the user, so:

```
$user->roles()->attachRole($role->id);
```

Should be

```
$user->attachRole($role); OR $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
```

You can read more about it and find examples on: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#concepts

**UPDATE**

In your create function, you return the created users directly, so the function stops there. Change it, so you assign the created user, and return it later, after the role attaches.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'customers')->firstOrFail();
    $user->attachRole($role);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've trying the examples on github too. Just tried your suggestion and the role is still not inserted in database. Only the new user.

Comment: Yes, now is working correctly. I tough I've tried like this but seems like I didn't. Thanks for the help!