# Adding default role on registration Zizaco/entrust

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sorry I face problem on `Zizaco/entrust` when new user make registration, he didn't have a role,
I need to be client `Role`.

in the `RegisterController`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

     $role = Role::where('name','client')->firstOrFail();
     $user->attachRole($role);
     return $user;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that shows seems at first sight correct. I assume that you have followed the configuration instructions of github izaco/entrust, is that correct?

If not, i recommend that you go to the page where we tell you how to configure and how to use it. There they explain it much better than I can do around here.

[github izaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#configuration)

I've also found a question similar to yours, right here on stackoverflow

[stackoverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148415/adding-default-role-on-registration-with-entrust-and-laravel-5-6)

I hope this can help you find the answer you are looking for.
A cordial greeting.

**Updated**
I went back to review your code and it had not fallen in that you do a return, I had tested it directly in a variable and that's why it worked for me. I'm sorry I did not notice before.

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

**Change it for**

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

Actually I was like this, in the related question that I found and attach as a link.

Anyway, I'm glad you solved it for yourself. A cordial greeting.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes I have followed the configuration instructions of github izaco/entrust, I'll keeping search :)

Comment: It is very strange that it does not work for you, since i have verified that your code is correct and it works for me.
Maybe if you review the models, traits and other configurations there is something that can explain that it does not work.
I hope you solve it soon. Good Luck. @HimaHima

Comment: I have modified my answer. I'm glad you solved it for yourself. A cordial greeting. @HimaHima

Answer (score 0):

I Used this and it works very well:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
   $userModel = new User();
        $userModel->name = $data['name'];
        $userModel->email = $data['email'];
        $userModel->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
        $userModel->save();

        $role = Role::where('name', 'client')->first();
        $userModel->roles()->attach($role->id);
        return $userModel;
}
```